# How to open this recessed faucet aerator? It seems very hidden inside!

Tags: repair, faucet

We need to install a faucet filter and have a problem removing our kitchen faucet recessed aerator.

I googled and saw some examples on YouTube but not sure if our recessed aerator is same as the ones on the videos.

We already tried using a anti-slip cloth to squeeze the aerator and also use an adjustable wrench to open it but all didn’t work.

Please let us know if you know what else we could try to open it.

[image]

**Updated photo**

[image]

Comment: More info is needed.  A photo from the side may help and if you know the maker and model number.

Comment: I just uploaded a picture from the side of the faucet. It looks like a regular one but it’s deeply plugged inside so adjustable crescent doesn’t hold really well..

Comment: If I click on the link above the first picture, I can see the notches inside the rim on the edge.

Comment: if possible, please provide brand/model of the facuet..

Comment: I wish I could but there is no name or model info... this is a faucet in our house’s kitchen. It’s already there when we moved in...

Comment: Hopefully when you get this thing out the water filter adapter will be the correct size to fit. There are after all quite a few different sizes and thread pitches on these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please just grip it with pliers and unscrew it (counter/anti-clockwise if you are looking directly at it). Don't worry about damage, they are like $3 US.

Answer (score 1):

From the original posted picture, it appears that you have the type that needs an aerator wrench.
See link below 
[aerator with wrench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcgZH.jpg)
To remove the aerator, without the specific wrench, try using a pin wench.  
The aerator is inside the faucet, so you will not be able to use slip grip, etc. on the outside. 
Those two notches are what you have to grap to be able to twist the aerator off.  By luck, a very thin long nose plier may be able to work.
The wrench cost about a $1 at HD or Lowes.

This is where the notches would be located based on original pictures. The notches would be located inside the rim. 
[image]

Your image showing location of notches. 
Sorry If I mislead you,  After closer exam of the side view, maybe this in not a notched aeration.  Can you provide a complete picture of the side view of the end of the facuet.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcgZH.jpg):[image: Notch location] https://www.zoro.com/american-standard-aerator-metering-brass-m962393-0020a/i/G0853912/

Comment: Nice answer but i am not sure i  see any notches ( maybe )  that the keys of the aerator wrench would fit into. The photo is rather blurry. The pin spanner  idea is worth a try.

Comment: It appears to be two notches at 12 and 6 o clock in your picture.

Comment: @Programmer66: thanks for your suggestion but I don’t think it has any notches to use the tool you said above. The aerator looks like a regular one with half of it installed hidden and half shown. But to get hold of the half shown it’s very slippery..

Comment: The notch is inside, not outside the opening,  Your original picture from underneath looking into the aerator showed the notches.  Notches not visible from the outside.  If possible, look inside the faucet where the water comes out.  On the edge, inside, there will be two notches.

Comment: perhaps post a picture from below so we can see what you see

Comment: Sorry for the low quality of my previous photo. Could you please take a look at my updated photo? I couldn’t see any notches. Probably in previous photos those are just reflection of something but there is no notch I can see on the aerator. My guess is that the aerator looks like a regular internal threaded faucet. The bottom is very regular and does not show any notches.. I’m so into getting the aerator out to install water filter but it has been a whole afternoon and it hasn’t even moved..

Comment: take this hack at your risk of damaging the surface for the aerator, shouldn't matter since you are replacing it with filter.  Use a rag and a Vise-grip type plier, protecting the exposed surface of the aerator.  Slowly clamp on the aerator only to grip the aerator, and do a twist.  Looking from above, it would be clock-wise. if  using the rag is too slippery, use the Vise-Grip type plier directly.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll try and see it it works